# Is there a way to get rid of this mark in swiftui picker?

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker

[image]

Development Environment XCode 14.0.1
Working on SwiftUI version 13
application code

```
Button(action: {}) {
                            ZStack {
                                Picker("", selection: $month){
                                    ForEach(0..<months.count, id: \.self) { index in
                                        Text("\(months[index])")
                                    }
                                }
                                .accentColor(.black).padding(.trailing, 30)
                                .tag(3)
                                Image("bul_drop_down").position(x: 75, y: 26)
                            }
                        }.buttonStyle(SelectBtnStyle(width: 100))
```

I want to get rid of that ^ mark

Comment: It's part of the component. Without some hacks it isn't possible

Comment: why you have used `buttonStyle`?

Comment: I've never seen such a mark in many apps. Should I use a component other than the Picker ? Button style was used to decorate borders, etc. Even if you remove the style, the display will remain.